# Wrong Output On HTML Table From Nawk Script

Tags: html, linux, unix, awk, nawk

`$3` is for the 3rd column of `.txt` which represents my email address column.  Why is the following statement outputing `"$3"` rather than the email address?:

```
print "      <td><a href=mailto:>$3</a></td>"
```

I am at a standstill.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are printing a literal string, what you want is:

```
print "      <td><a href=mailto:>"$3"</a></td>"
```